# How can I upvote answers and comments?

Tags: support, voting, up-votes

Could someone please point me in the right direction on how to "upvote" a comment or answer?

It appears a rather stupid question, but I have received some very useful support on these sites and I would like to upvote some of the comments I have received.

Comment: You click the triangle above or below the number of votes?

Comment: The _comments_ or the _answers_?

Comment: With regards to questions, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/about And with regards to comments, there is an up-arrow that appears when moving your cursor over a comment. Click it and you've upvoted.

Comment: @user1624926: great question! was looking for something like this to reply to your comment on SO but couldn't find it here. Now also this  problem is solved... :-)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is an up & down triangle before the question and answer, just hit them and you can vote for it. Up Triangle refers to upvote and down triangle refers to downvote/negative voting.

> [image]

For Questions and answers, you can do both upvote & downvote, while for comments you can only do upvote, you can't downvote a comment.

But for voting you require at least 15 reputations, see this [privileges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges).

Whenever you upvote an answer or a question, the user will get `+10` reputation (you can not upvote your own question/answer or comments) while upvoting a comment doesn't reward in reputation.

For downvote, if you downvote a question it doesn't costs you, while if you downvote any answer, you will lose `-1` from your reputation too. If someone else downvotes your post (question or answer) then you lose `-2` from your reputation.